# how to scrolling images using page conrtol in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01NacQ8-ojE

> > How to scrolling images using page control using swift?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a image scroller while programmatically or using storyboard but here is a simplest tutorial of image scroller using storyboard using Swift3

http://sweettutos.com/2015/04/13/how-to-make-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-storyboards-swift/

Furthermore you can also download project with complete source code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this by using horizontal scrollview instead of pageView controller. Use scrollView delegate methods to scroll each image.

Here is the simple tutorial for doing that:
[PageView Controller with scrollView](http://www.iostutorialjunction.com/2016/09/how-to-create-pageviewcontroller-in-ios-using-swift-language-tutorial.html)